# How does PHP date() function work?

Tags: php, date, time, timezone

I'm just wondering how the php function `date()` works? Like how does it determine time and date to return?

For example if my php code on a page looked something like this:

```
<?php    
    echo date("h:i:sa");
?>
```

It will simply echo out (for example) `11:18:24am`, but let's say a site visitor from another country visits page, will the time returned be appropriate for their timezone? Hopefully this question makes sense, i only ask because I couldn't find anything on Google when searching how php `date()` function works.

Comment: see also http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: No, the time of the server will always be returned.

Comment: Because PHP is server-side all dates/times are based on the server's timezone.

Comment: `date()` isn't magically aware of the timezone of any visitors, it doesn't know anything about them, including what country/timezone they might be in; you have to tell it what timezone should be used if anything other than your server/default timezone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date method is documented here: https://secure.php.net/manual/function.date.php

As php scripts are executed on server side, it uses the current date/time of the server, formats and returns it. - There is no conversions for the timezone of visitors of your website. If you need localized times, you need to change the [timezone manually](https://php.net/manual/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: Thanks for the info, answers my question :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but here is how i solved it. In the php.ini the timezone is static and set according to the server but you can override this by using date_default_time_zone function. for example you can create a script that tests a visitor location then loads parameters to date_default_timezone_set("continent/city"); according to your visitor location. i hope this works